# How to write Junit test cases for the below code?

Tags: java, junit, junit4, junit5

```java
public class FirstAssignment {

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        
        Scanner kb = new Scanner(System.in);
        int i = kb.nextInt();
        
        if(i%15==0)
        {
            System.out.print("BOOTCAMPsystems ");
        
        } else if(i%5==0)
        {
            System.out.print("systems ");
            
        }else if(i%3==0)
        {
            System.out.print("BOOTCAMP ");
            
        } else 
            System.out.print(i+" ");
        
        
    }
    
}
```

I am trying to take user input and:

1. Print 'BOOTCAMP' for multiples of 3
2. Print 'systems' for multiples of 5
3. Print 'BOOTCAMPsystems' for multiples of 15.

Please help in designing unit test cases for this.

Comment: I would move your code into a method that takes an `int` as input and returns a `String`, then you can `print` that `String` from `main`.  Then you can unit test the method and compare the output of the `String` to the expected output.

Comment: I am printing both string and integer so how can I return a String from the method?

Comment: Just convert the integer to a `String` when you return it, it does not need to stay as an `int`.

Comment: public class FirstAssignment {

     
  public String Test(int a)
  {
   Scanner kb = new Scanner(System.in);
   int i = kb.nextInt();

  if(i%15==0)
  {
   return "BOOTCAMPsystems ";
  
  } else if(i%5==0)
  {
   return "systems ";
   
  }else if(i%3==0)
  {
   return "BOOTCAMP ";
   
  } else
  {
   return Integer.toString(i);
  }
  
 } 
}            I moved my code to a method now how to print that string from main method?

Answer (score 2):

Currently you immediately `print` all of the results which would make it hard to unit test. I would move the code into a separate method that takes an `int` as a parameter and `return` a `String` with the result.  You can then unit test this method with an input integer to the expected output of `String` and also `print` the result from `main`.

Your changed code would look like this:

```
public class FirstAssignment {

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        Scanner kb = new Scanner(System.in);
        int i = kb.nextInt();

        System.out.println(checkSystems(i));
    }

    public static String checkSystems(int i) {

        String str;
        if (i % 15 == 0) {
            str = "BOOTCAMPsystems ";
        } 
        else if (i % 5 == 0) {
            str = "systems ";
        } 
        else if (i % 3 == 0) {
            str = "BOOTCAMP ";
        } 
        else {
            str = i + " ";
        }
        return str;

    }
}
```

You can then make a Junit test class like below:

```
class TestFirstAssignment {

    @Test
    void testCheckSystems1() {
        String result = FirstAssignment.checkSystems(1);
        assertEquals(result, "1 ");
    }

    @Test
    void testCheckSystems3() {
        String result = FirstAssignment.checkSystems(3);
        assertEquals(result, "BOOTCAMP ");
    }
    
    @Test
    void testCheckSystems5() {
        String result = FirstAssignment.checkSystems(5);
        assertEquals(result, "systems ");
    }
    
    @Test
    void testCheckSystems15() {
        String result = FirstAssignment.checkSystems(15);
        assertEquals(result, "BOOTCAMPsystems ");
    }
    
    @Test
    void testCheckSystems18() {
        String result = FirstAssignment.checkSystems(18);
        assertEquals(result, "BOOTCAMP ");
    }
}
```

These test cases will check some of the cases, you can add more cases as you see fit such as cases that *should* fail.  Your successful cases will appear green like the below image:

[image: Successful Runs]